# declaring cython cdef methods with except in child types

Tags: python, exception, cython, cpython

In cython functions and methods declared using the cdef statement which might raise python errors must be declared with some version of `except -1` in the declaration. More info [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values)

I'm wondering if it's possible to use `except -1` on a method of an extension type if that method was not defined with `except -1` in the parent type. An example might help here. I want my `LazyCow` to raise an exception when `moo` is called. This works fine for `beLazy` because the parent `Cow` type does not have a matching method but for the `moo` method, the exception is ignored.

```
cdef class Cow:

    cdef int moo(self):
        print 'moooooooo'
        return 0

cdef class LazyCow(Cow):

    cdef int moo(self) except -1:
        raise ValueError("I don't want to moo")

    cdef int beLazy(self) except -1:
        raise ValueError("I don't want to be lazy")

def run():
    cdef LazyCow cow

    cow = LazyCow()
    print "Running moo"
    cow.moo()
    print ""
    print "Running beLazy"
    cow.beLazy()
```

When I call run I get the following, the error raised in `moo` is ignored and but `beLazy` works as expected.

```
Running moo
Exception ValueError: ValueError("I don't want to moo",) in 'cowExample.LazyCow.moo' ignored

Running beLazy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-157c9bda2cd6> in <module>()
----> 1 run()

/tmp/cowExample.so in cowExample.run (cowExample.c:784)()

/tmp/cowExample.so in cowExample.LazyCow.beLazy (cowExample.c:685)()

ValueError: I don't want to be lazy
```

My question, is this a bug in cython? If not why do I not either A) get the behavior I expect or B) get a warning/error at compile time that my method declarations do not match.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Report it on the Cython list.